# Get AWS S3 Presigned URL for a bucket object in typescript NextJS so that browser side can download a file with @aws-sdk/S3Client

Tags: typescript, next.js

This is using v3 of the S3Client. All the existing examples I can find use the old aws-sdk package. I need the client (browser) to download a file from S3 without divulging the key from the backend. As far as I can tell, this is the correct way to do this. So far I have used `const presigned = await signer.presign(request);` from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.html docs but I don't know how to construct `request`. Can somebody please advise?

Answer (score 1):

pages/api/file.ts:

```
import { GetObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export interface GetFileProps {
  url: string;
}

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<GetFileProps>,
) {
  const s3client = new S3Client({
    region: "region",
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: "",
      secretAccessKey: "",
    },
  });

  const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: "bucketName",
    Key: req.query.path as string,
  });

  const url = await getSignedUrl(s3client, command, { expiresIn: 900 });
  res.status(200).json({ url });
}
```

The frontend can then use that URL:

```
  const aRef = React.useRef<any>();

  const getUrlAndDownload = React.useCallback((path: string) => {
    from(fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/file?path=${path}`))
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(response => {
          return response.json();
        }),
        mergeMap((res: GetFileProps) => {
          aRef.current.href = res.url;
          aRef.current.click();
          return EMPTY;
        }),
        catchError(err => {
          console.log("Error fetching download URL", err);
          return err;
        }),
      )
      .subscribe();
  }, []);
```

And in the tsx:

```
      <a ref={aRef} />
```

And something can call getUrlAndDownload from an onClick with the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I was working around for the solution I tried to get the URL, but it didn't work as expected. then I think of something different.
well, you may not need a signed URL to display the image in the browser here is what I did to solve the problem:
simply get the image from the S3 bucket and then send the client `response.Body` because `response.Body` will have a buffer object that holds the image. you can modify the header if needed.

> File Location: pages/api/id/image/[...id].ts

```js
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
import S3 from "aws-sdk/clients/s3"; // configure aws global credentials
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import ConnectDb from "../../middleware/Mongoose";
import type { ResponseData } from "../../models/ApiResponse";

if (process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID) {
  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });
}
const path = "users/";
const s3 = new S3();
const get = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>) => {
  try {
    let input = req.query?.id || [];
    let userId = input[0];
    let name = input[1];
    if (!userId || !name)
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Please provide user id and image name",
      });
    const face = await s3
      .getObject({
        Bucket: process.env.AWS_SECRET_BUCKET as string,
        Key: path + userId + "/" + name,
      })
      .promise();

    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    res.end(face.Body);
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.log(e, "error");
    return res
      .status(200)
      .json({ success: false, message: "error: " + e.message });
  }
};
export default ConnectDb(
  async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>) => {
    try {
      return req.method === "GET"
        ? await get(req, res)
        : res.status(404).json({ success: true, message: "404 not Found" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res
        .status(500)
        .json({ success: false, message: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
  }
);
```

your front-end code:

```html
 <img src={`/api/id/image/${el.user._id}/front.jpeg`} alt=""/>
```